# C# наполнение массива textBox'ами

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms, textbox

Прошу помощи в работе с массивами.

Имеем на n-ое кол-во TextBox'ов (TextBox1, TextBox2... TextBox'n'), где n - известное число, для примера примем n=3.

```
string[] massiv = new string[n];
massiv[0] = TextBoxArray1.Text;
massiv[1] = TextBoxArray2.Text;
massiv[2] = TextBoxArray3.Text;
```

Сам вопрос: как сократить запись через цикл for? 
Пробовал вот такой способ:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    massiv[i] = TextBoxArray+i.Text;
}
```

Но в данном случае студия ругается на `TextBox+i.Text`
Сбор массива должен происходить из TextBox'ов с определенным именем (Например TextBoxArray1)

Comment: А зачем вы насоздавали эти TextBox1, TextBox2 и т.д? Создавайте и сразу помещайте в массив

Comment: Зачем насоздавал TextBox'ы? Отличный вопрос :) Но ответ я Вам конечно же не дам, но скажу просто: учусь, интересно все это.

Comment: Ну тогда гуглите что-то вроде "поиск контрола по имени c#", скорее всего одной из первых ссылок будет ответ на ruSO. Потом можете отметить свой вопрос как дубликат того :)

Comment: Смотрите ответ, который я вам указал, просто склеивайте строку имени: `"TextBoxArray" + i.ToString()` и ищите тем методом, что в указанном ответе

Answer (score 0):

Все элементы textbox можно взять из свойтсва Controls

```
TextBox[] textBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToArray();

string[] massiv = new string[textBoxes.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Length; i++)
{
    massiv[i] = textBoxes[i].Text;
}
```

Comment: Тут как я понял идет поиск по всем TextBox'ам. Но нужно собрать массив из TextBox'ов только с определенным именем.

Comment: @СаняИванов `textBoxes.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("TextBoxArray")`